# How to avoid black screen in android while my app is loading?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-windowmanager

How to avoid  black screen in android while my app is loading ?  I have removed all things from onCreate to AsyncTask but still I have black screen at the beginning. My default ( first ) activity is Main and if there is one parameter I momentarily load Personal activity withou showing Main, otherwise I show Main activity. Can anyone suggest me solution ?
I tried with http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/ but it doesn't help.

Comment: Post some code - it might help or we are just guessing...

Comment: see the solution here : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#themed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

i'm not sure.

but, Try this in **`Manifest`** inside your `activity`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

I have seen a good solution about splash screen... hope it useful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654361/762919

Comment: I was struggling for so long. This solved my issue. Just adding the line in Manifest did the trick. Thanks April.

Comment: thanks, this give me an idea to make a custom theme like flash and it solved my problem. For those who are looking for same answer this is how i do it It worked for me hope it help you guys too. In style.xml                                                       <style name="MySplashTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_image</item>
</style>                                                                  Manifest file in activity tag                 android:theme="@style/MySplashTheme"

Comment: But there is a problem with this solution, it locks your screen orientation to portrait.. ;(

Answer (score 14):

Add below line in your android style.xml file in style tag  .

```
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Complete code :

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: My app finished with this

Answer (score 3):

Optimize ur code,try to reduce code from onCreate(),this was issue faced by me i solved it by reducing code in onCreate().

Best of Luck

Answer (score 1):

Since you have cleared out your onCreate() and assigned your initialization tasks to a worker thread, the fact that your screen nonetheless remains dark for a while after your app is launched is probably due to the complexity of the *graphics* in your initial display (rather than to your initialization code, which is probably model-related, rather than view-related).

The solution that you say worked for you is to use a visible background as your theme.  I'm glad that you found that to be adequate, but for some purposes a more specific (e.g., logo / app name) splash screen (which displays quickly because it uses much simpler graphics) would be more desirable.

Please see the answer linked below for a detailed description (with sample code) of how a splash screen that displays quickly can be implemented:

[Create a true splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519649/create-a-true-splash-screen/10202161#10202161)

This also discusses the approach that you have accepted above.