# Black Screen Android Applications

Tags: java, android, network-programming, splash-screen

I see a black screen between switching activities in my android app. To my knowledge Black is the default plot color for Android, so this is the placeholder until the app completes it's layout operation. There are a number of things that can cause an app to have a delay:
1. Performing a network call(s).
2. Loading data from disk.
3. Garbage collection from other tasks.
4. Restoring a complex drawing.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817568/how-to-avoid-black-screen-in-android-while-my-app-is-loading) and links it had and I have tried various techniques to optimize the application such as multi threading etc. I KNOW now that my issue is with network calls and that there is a delay in the functions when there are latency issues i.e. when there is slow internet the function that I use to "check for internet" and "fetch and parse data" work slowly as it is dependent on the internet speed. Changing the application flow and activity life cycle is not possible as they are strictly set as per the functional requirements. Is there a way to solve or a workaround to this issue that can be done? These are snippets of code that I have implemented in my splash screen and there are similar codes inside other activities. This is a code that checks for internet connection in the onCreate.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    chkStatus(this);
}
public boolean chkStatus(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() && isOnline()) {
        Log.e("connectedto", "Wifi");
        session.StoreMode("online");
        return true;
    } else if (mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting() && isOnline()) {
        Log.e("connectedto", "Mobile 3G");
        session.StoreMode("online");
        return true;
    } else {
        session.StoreMode("offline");
        Log.e("connectedto", "No Network ");
        return false;
    }
}
public Boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal == 0);
        return reachable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are switching to other activity and also what are you doing in other activity if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the contentView in your onCreateMethod:

Add this line after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for noticing but it was present in the original code and I missed it while copping it here. That was not the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was happening. Somehow the function "isOnline" was being called before the splash screen. So when ever there was low internet network speed, the function was stuck and there was a black screen before the splash screen as the time of the splash screen got over before ack of the ping came back.So I removed the function from the splash screen and put it inside other activities.